# Как избежать ошибки NameError: name 'unrate' is not defined?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, анализ-данных

Объясните, что делать, чтобы не вылезала такая ошибка: `"NameError: name 'unrate' is not defined"` в jupyter notebook?

Пишу код, сохраняю, закрываю файл с написанным кодом, завтра опять приступаю к писанию, открываю этот же файл, вылезает эта ошибка. Я нажимаю Kernel, далее restart&run all, ошибка исчезает.

Но если у меня много строк кода, и есть такие строки, которые нельзя дважды считать/перезапускать (допустим, исследую таблицу в 100 000 строк и использую Series.map), то что делать?

Ниже пример кода:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import pandas as pd
    unrate = pd.read_csv(r"/тропинка_к_коду/unrate.csv")
    unrate['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(unrate['DATE'])
    unrate.head(12)
    plt.plot(unrate["DATE"].head(12), unrate["VALUE"].head(12))
```

захожу на следующий день:

```
   print(unrate)

   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-5844a0f8d885> in <module>
----> 1 print(unrate)

NameError: name 'unrate' is not defined
```

Если мне нужно продолжать исследовать датасет, я не могу этого сделать, jupyter notebook "не видит" эту таблицу. (для аналогии: пишу диплом в Microsoft Word, и каждый день дописываю новую главу, при этом уже написанные главы сохраняются, в jupyter notebook можно также с кодом?)

Comment: Убрать из кода использование несуществующей переменной unrate, например?

Comment: Приведите [mre]

Answer (score 3):

Я бы вам посоветовал после того как вы обработали данные и получили датасет, с которым вы хотите работать далее, сохранить этот готовый датасет в бинарном формате, например в формате `Parquet`, `HDF5` или `Pickle` файла. Если вам нужно будет читать данные целиком из файла, то я бы выбрал `Parquet` - совместимый, поддерживает компрессию и один из наиболее быстрых форматов.

Установка:

```
conda install -n <your_py_environment_name> pyarrow python-snappy
```

Пример сохранения датасета:

```
df.to_parquet(r"c:\project\ds_ready.parquet")
```

Пример чтения датасета:

```
df2 = pd.read_parquet(r"c:\project\ds_ready.parquet")
```

Таким образом вы можете только лишь импортировать все необходимые модули и загрузить уже обработанные ранее данные из бинарного файла, вместо того, чтобы выполнять *все* ячейки Jupyter Notebook.

---

> почему лучше хранить данные в бинарном, а не в текстовом виде?

При сохранении/загрузке данных в/из бинарного формата, данные о типах данных сохраняются и нам не нужна снова парсить данные и определять правильный тип данных, формат даты/времент и т.д. Кроме того бинарные форматы хранения данных поддерживают сжатие, что позволяет экономить место на диске и быстрее читать данные, т.к. распаковка данных в памяти часто работает гораздо быстрее по сравнению со чтением несжатых данных. Ещё некоторые бинарные форматы, например HDF5, поддерживают индексирование и чтение части данных по индексу - это позволяет хранить датасеты, которые не помещаются в памяти и читать и обрабатывать данные по частям (по индексу).

Comment: Мне feather понравился в свое время из форматов. Ну очень быстрый.

Comment: @CrazyElf, Parquet - можно считать его более продвинутой и более быстрой версией ;) Кстати автор Feather - это создатель Pandas и сейчас он работает над проектом Apache Arrow (Python-arrow)

Comment: Про Arrow я давно ещё читал, как его хвалили и вроде хотели внутри Pandas переделать хранение данных с numpy на arrow или что-то вроде того, но что-то потом про это ничего больше уже не попадалось мне.

Comment: @CrazyElf, Pandas при чтении/записи Parquet по умолчанию использует PyArrow. Возможно именно поэтому так быстро читаются Parquet файлы...

Answer (score 2):

Я так понимаю, у вас `Jupyter Notebook` и какая-то мешанина кода. Надо смотреть на ваш код, иначе можно только гадать. Например, можно предположить, что вы где-то используете переменную `unrate`, а потом делаете `del unrate` и если запускать ячейки подряд через `run all`, то всё ок - переменная создаётся и потом удаляется. А если вы потом уже запускаете отдельно какую-то ячейку или выполняете функцию, где используется эта переменная `unrate` (и она там была ещё не удалена когда вы делали `run all`) - вы видите ошибку, потому что у вас уже выполнилась инструкция `del unrate` и такой переменной в памяти больше нет.

`Jupyter Notebook` - очень коварная в этом плане штука, там очень сложно отследить последовательность выполнения кода и состояние переменных, если вы прыгаете по ячейкам и выполняете их не последовательно.